# DrawerLayout with completely transparent status bar

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, drawerlayout, material-components-android

I'm trying to achieve a completely transparent status bar with a full-screen DrawerLayout exactly like in the new IO19 app :

[image]

The regular transparent status bar effect is always having a transparent grey background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set NavigationView's insetForeground to transparent

```
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nv_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:insetForeground="@android:color/transparent" />
```